# HtttpClient async method throws TaskCanceledExceptionat first time execution

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient

I have noticed some curious behavior of execution methods of `HttpClient` (`SendAsync`, `GetStringAsync` and other XxxAsync). I have using this class to login on numbers of servers and execute some of their functions, I've doing it in loop and noticed that after executing my app it wait some time and report about failing at first server, and others are good, if try it again it report about success. So have debug this method and noticed that in first time of executing `HttpClient.SendAsync` it throws `TaskCanceledException` which is in fact `TimeOutException` because in HttpClient no one throws that exception( must be some new style of coding designed by Microsoft). 
So I have write some simple example of it:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            foo();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    static async void foo()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((await Ping()).ToString());
        }
    }

    static async Task<bool> Ping()
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            var m_HttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                UseCookies = false
            };
            HttpClient m_client = new HttpClient(m_HttpHandler);
            m_client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4);

            var response = await m_client.GetStringAsync("http://google.com/");
            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and this gave me that output

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Task canceled.
in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
in MainClass.<LogOn>d__2.MoveNext() в C:\Users\HRR\Documents\Visual Studio 201
5\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs: string 35
False
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

Actualy it doesn't throw Exception everytime, some times it doesn't, on some PC it's works just okey (I've tested it on win10 and win8 machines and it work well every time), but on Win7 (tested on 2 computers) it's throw Exception...
So what's the problem with it?

PS At my solution I have some chunk that dealing with it.

**Update**
I've tried on the default 100 seconds and it looks like it's connecting about 14 seconds first time, next ones spend much less a second for each...

Comment: Your code looks fine. Only thing I can see is that you are setting a timeout for the request and in some cases it is most likely timing out.

Comment: It is, but I can't understand how it can be only in the first time of calling Ping() method, and why it doesn't on Win8/10 PCs?

Comment: Is there an InnerException in there?

Comment: When the first connection takes that long time, is that on a server OS? Does the same happen on a client OS?

Comment: No, there isn't inner exception.

Comment: It's on client Windows 7, and actualy it's not really connection time, I believe there's something more, becouse if I will set set timeout for first connection microsecunds, it will throw exception, and after that other connection will work good and wouldn't spent even second...

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with `m_client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(15)`. This means a timeout of 15 ticks, which obviously times out before receiving and answer.

With this timeout, I get your `TaskCanceledException` too. *So it seems your exceptions are thrown when the request times out.*

I assume that `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` starts a task with a `CancellationToken` and that it signals that token after the timeout. And the inner task throws the `TaskCanceledException`, because it could not finish it's purpose successfully.

UPDATE:
On the question why there are sometimes timouts on the first try only: I don't have too detailed knowledge, but as far as I remember, Windows manages the band widths for processes. You can see that if you copy large files in your network: the speed increases slowly, but when you start another network requiring process, the speed drops fast and recovers slowly again when the other process is stopped. So I'm not suprised that you get a timeout at first try and get results in the following requests.

Comment: Yes it is, TaskCanceledException in my case is a TimeOutException, but I have quastion why it throws just in first time of running the program and in my case, just in Win7, and doesn't on Win10 or 8;

Comment: Well I don't know the configuration of your network, but with a timeout of 4 seconds it is not so suprising that some clients always get results and others have problems. And that it works after a timeout on the first try can be explained by how windows manages band widths (which I can't explain at detail). If you want to know why your clients have different network timeouts, this would be a different question. I tried to answer on the `TaskCanceledException`.

Comment: Actualy I have try it on 10 seconds too, and it ridiculous to connect that time... However I've tried on the default 100 seconds and it looks like it's connecting about 14 seconds first time, next ones spend much less a second for each...

Comment: Just as I said :) but cannot tell you how to improve your connectivity.